# WebApi field filtering without using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am building WebApi2 project to expose some RESTful service. Let's say I have following model objects.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }

    public int Status { get; set; }

    public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public DateTime Expiry { get; set; }
}
```

In my service I have to go to 2 different systems to retrieve data for Person and the account info of the Person. Obviously the service implementation looks like

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Person/{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
    {
        var person = new Person();
        person = GetPersonFromSystemA(id);

        if (person.Status == 2)
        {
            person.Accounts = GetPersonAccountsFromSystemB(id);
        }

        return this.Ok(person);
    }
```

I cannot use EF at all in this case, so OData is very tricky.

I have some requirement that I need to provide the filtering capability to the service client. The client can decide which fields of the objects to return, it also means that if the client does not like to include Accounts info of the person I should skip the second call to system B to avoid entire child object.

I did some quick search but I could not find some similar solution yet. I know I can implement my own filtering syntax, and have all custom codes to use the filtering (by having lots of if/else).

I am looking for some ideas of more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is not required for building an OData Service. If you do not use OData, you will probably have to implement your own IQueryable which is what OData does out of the box.

Some sample code.

**Model classes with some added properties**

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public String Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public List<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    [Key]
    public String Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expiry { get; set; }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", null, GetEdmModel(), new DefaultODataBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
        config.EnsureInitialized();
    }

    private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.Namespace = "YourNamespace";
        builder.ContainerName = "DefaultContainer";
        builder.EntitySet<Person>("People");
        builder.EntitySet<Account>("Accounts");
        var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
        return edmModel;
    }
}
```

Controller method

```
[EnableQuery]
public class PeopleController : ODataController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(SomeDataSource.Instance.People.AsQueryable());
    }
}
```

You will need to include the **Microsoft.AspNet.OData** Nuget package.

Refer to the following for more guidance. It uses an in memory data source, but the concept is the same regardless.

http://www.odata.org/blog/how-to-use-web-api-odata-to-build-an-odata-v4-service-without-entity-framework/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, your implementation assumes I have to get all data first regardless they are useful or not, then apply the filtering. If EF/OData implementation uses lazy loading the date filtered out won't be loaded at all. I also try to achieve similar feature to load the data I need only since it is expensive to call external systems.

Answer (score 0):

When building a web api you would often want to filter your response and get only certain fields. You could do it in many ways, one of which as suggested above. Another way, you could approach it is using data shaping in your web api.

If you had a controller action as such:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(string fields="all")
{
    try
    {
        var results = _tripRepository.Get();
        if (results == null)
            return NotFound();
        // Getting the fields is an expensive operation, so the default is all,
        // in which case we will just return the results
        if (!string.Equals(fields, "all", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var shapedResults = results.Select(x => GetShapedObject(x, fields));
            return Ok(shapedResults);
        }
        return Ok(results);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return InternalServerError();
    }
}
```

And then your GetShapedData method can do the filtering as such:

```
public object GetShapedObject<TParameter>(TParameter entity, string fields)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fields))
        return entity;
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^,()]+(\([^()]*\))?");
    var requestedFields = regex.Matches(fields).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Distinct();
    ExpandoObject expando = new ExpandoObject();

    foreach (var field in requestedFields)
    {
        if (field.Contains("("))
        {
            var navField = field.Substring(0, field.IndexOf('('));

            IList navFieldValue = entity.GetType()
                                    ?.GetProperty(navField, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                                    ?.GetValue(entity, null) as IList;
            var regexMatch = Regex.Matches(field, @"\((.+?)\)");
            if (regexMatch?.Count > 0)
            {
                var propertiesString = regexMatch[0].Value?.Replace("(", string.Empty).Replace(")", string.Empty);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertiesString))
                {
                    string[] navigationObjectProperties = propertiesString.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    List<object> list = new List<object>();
                    foreach (var item in navFieldValue)
                    {
                        list.Add(GetShapedObject(item, navigationObjectProperties));
                    }

                    ((IDictionary<string, object>)expando).Add(navField, list);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var value = entity.GetType()
                          ?.GetProperty(field, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                          ?.GetValue(entity, null);
            ((IDictionary<string, object>)expando).Add(field, value);
        }
    }

    return expando;
}
```

Check my blog for a detailed post: https://jinishbhardwaj.wordpress.com/2016/12/03/web-api-supporting-data-shaping/

Comment: That is a good solution to shape the result, I will look into it. Thanks.